# Event when wordwrapping

Tags: html, word-wrap

When doing websites for both pc and mobile, responsive design, the line widths and fontsizes often can vary wildly. Especially headings can wrap on inappr-opriat-e places, if the content creator is not aware of the problem.

Is there a way of letting a crawler scan the site for browser-forced wordwraps, or having a javascript event fire on wordwrapping?

If I know the problem I know how to put &shy; in, but I don't want to have to put them into every word every where, just when needed.

---

### Taumatawhakatangihangakoauauotamateaturipukakapikimaungahoronukupokaiwhenuakitanatahu is a hill on New Zealand's North Island.

---

is a valid example

Answer (score 1):

While not a JavaScript solution, the [CSS `hyphens` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/hyphens) can handle automatic hyphenation for you, acting as if you had inserted `&shy;` hyphen markers throughout the document.

```
.hyphens {
    hyphens: auto;
}
```

Proper hyphenation points are determined according to the language set in the document or the element.

```
<p lang='en' class='hyphens'>Content containing extremely long words</p>
```

Unfortunately, the `hyphens` property isn't fully supported by Chrome (see [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-hyphens)) but maybe this will someday change. Other major browsers all support the feature at this time.

A library called [Hyphenator](https://github.com/mnater/hyphenator) exists and offers support for automatic hyphenation for browsers that otherwise don't support `hyphens: auto` or lack specific language hyphenation patterns.

Comment: Can this be used for the body tag? Any reason not to?

Comment: @LeifNeland I can't think of any reason not to do that.